# send email from event in shopware6 programmatically

Tags: email, events, shopware, shopware6

I am working on a customer mapping event in Shopware6.In this event, I want to send an email.
guide me on how can I do that.

version: shopware 6.4.12

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a custom Flowbuilder trigger and event, which you can use to send an email automatically.

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/flow/add-flow-builder-action

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/flow/add-flow-builder-trigger